# How to make an object move from top to bottom in Lua?

Tags: lua, position, drawing

In a game I'm making, there's a square where the game is happening inside. I want the circles that spawn in to start at the top and travel down to the bottom. In the original program, they travel from left to right. How would I go about this? I don't know how to get it to start at the top and travel down instead of starting at the left and traveling to the right.

Here's the original code (I know it's a lot, sorry).  I am trying to help a friend.

```
--Made by Joms or /u/jomy582
--Please credit me if using this in a battle.

spawntimer = 0
timerspawn = 0
storedtime = Time.time

bullets = {}
bulletsbig = {}
bulletswarn = {}
dir = 1
bigheight = {33, 98}

function Update()
  spawntimer = spawntimer + (Time.dt*Time.mult)
  timerspawn = timerspawn + (Time.dt*Time.mult)

  --normal bullets
  --change the number in the if statement to make them spawn more frequently/less frequently
  --EX: spawntimer > 0.2 spawns them pretty fast
  --EX2: spawntimer > 1 spawns them pretty slow
  --Make sure to change the subtraction method in the if statement
  if spawntimer > 0.16 then
    spawntimer = spawntimer-0.16
    local bullet = CreateProjectile("bullet", -Arena.width/2, math.random(-Arena.height/2, Arena.height/2))
    bullet.SetVar("deadly", true)
    table.insert(bullets, bullet)
  end

  --warning. spawns a warning every 5 seconds
  --You could change it, but that may cause some bugs
  if timerspawn > 2.2 then
    timerspawn = timerspawn-2.2
    dir = math.random(1,2)
    local bulletwarn = CreateProjectile("warning", 0, Arena.height/2 - bigheight[dir])
    bulletwarn.SetVar("warningtimer", 0)
    bulletwarn.SetVar("soundtimer", 0)
    bulletwarn.SetVar("animtimer", 0)
    bulletwarn.SetVar("anim", 1)
    table.insert(bulletswarn, bulletwarn)
  end

  --controlling normal bullets
  --a simple method that moves the bullets 1 pixel each frame
  --you can change it by editing the bullet.move
  --EX: bullet.Move(5*Time.mult, 0) moves the bullets 5 pixels each frame
  for i=1, #bullets do
    local bullet = bullets[i]
    if bullet.isactive then
      bullet.Move(2*Time.mult, 0)
      if bullet.y > -Arena.height/2 then
        bullet.Remove()
      end
    end
  end

  --controlling warning timer
  --a method that controls the warning timer
  for i=1, #bulletswarn do
    local bullet = bulletswarn[i]
    if bullet.isactive then
      local warningtimer = bullet.GetVar("warningtimer") + (Time.mult*Time.dt)
      local soundtimer = bullet.GetVar("soundtimer") + (Time.mult*Time.dt)
      local animtimer = bullet.GetVar("animtimer") + (Time.mult*Time.dt)
      local bulletSprite = bullet.sprite
      local anim = bullet.GetVar("anim")

      --flashing colors
      --change the animtimer > TIME where time is how often you want the warning to blink
      --warnings last for 3 seconds. Can change that as well
      --to get different colors, find the rgb value of the color you want and insert them below
      if animtimer > 0.08 then
        animtimer = animtimer-0.08
        if anim == 1 then
          local r = 0 --put Red value here
          local g = 0 --put Green value here
          local b = 169 --put Blue value here
          bulletSprite.color = {r/255, g/255, b/255} -- changes the color to whatever you'd like. Uses RGB.
          bullet.SetVar("anim", 2)
        elseif anim == 2 then
          local r = 0 --put Red value here
          local g = 0 --put Green value here
          local b = 255 --put Blue value here
          bulletSprite.color = {r/255, g/255, b/255} -- changes the color to whatever you'd like. Uses RGB.
          bullet.SetVar("anim", 1)
        end
      end

      --plays a timer evert 10 frames for 3 seconds.
      --change the soundname to change the sound
      --change the soundtimer > 0.16 to change how often it plays
      --can change how long it lasts as well by changing the less than statement
      if soundtimer > 0.10 then
        soundtimer = soundtimer-0.10
        Audio.PlaySound("alarm")
      end

      --this controls when to spawn the bullets
      --change the statement to change how long the warning timer is
      if warningtimer > 2 then
        warningtimer = warningtimer-2
        Audio.PlaySound("shoot")
        local bullet1 = CreateProjectile("leftbigbullet", Arena.width/2+30, Arena.height/2 - bigheight[dir]) --where to spawn them
        bullet1.SetVar("speed", -4) --how fast
        bullet1.SetVar("deadly", true)
        local bullet2 = CreateProjectile("rightbigbullet", -Arena.width/2-30, Arena.height/2 - bigheight[dir]) --where to spawn them
        bullet2.SetVar("speed", 4) --how fast
        bullet2.SetVar("deadly", true)
        table.insert(bulletsbig, bullet1)
        table.insert(bulletsbig, bullet2)
        bullet.Remove()
      end

      bullet.SetVar("warningtimer", warningtimer)
      bullet.SetVar("animtimer", animtimer)
      bullet.SetVar("soundtimer", soundtimer)
    end
  end

  --controlling big bullets
  --this method controls the big bullets
  for i=1, #bulletsbig do
    local bullet = bulletsbig[i]
    if bullet.isactive then
      local speed = bullet.GetVar("speed")
      bullet.SendToBottom()
      bullet.Move(speed*Time.mult, 0)
      if bullet.absx > 700 or bullet.absx < -70 then
        bullet.Remove()
      end
    end
  end

end

function OnHit(bullet)
    if(bullet.getVar("deadly")) then
    Player.Hurt(3)
    end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Is this a mathematics question or a programming question?

Comment: What are the arguments to `bullet.Move`? Maybe they are the velocities in the x and y directions and you just have to swap them.

Comment: You just need to swap projectile's spawn x, y cords, swap `Arena.width` to `Arena.height`

Comment: This is a Roblox question afaik.